# Drawing Base64Encoded image as canvas background in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas

I am facing two problems with my code:

1) I am unable to add a Base64Encoded string image as a background in Canvas.
[image: Code]
[image: Code]

2) Anything I am drawing in my canvas using freehand, is not clipping at the bottom edge of the canvas 
[image: screenshot]

Would like to have some help in achieveing the bove two tasks please. I have attached my existing code as well.

=============================================================
UPDATE:
So, I finally manage to add the image on canvas, thanks for the help. The issue I have landed onto is to constraint the image inside the container, regardless of the image size. I have attached screenshots of two different image sizes to better illustrate my problem :

[image: ScreenShot 1]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to Base64 decode the string? What format is the binary image in? BMP, PNG? (Hopefully one of the supported ones.) Use `instantiateImageCodec` to convert the binary PNG into a `ui.Image` (NB that's different from the `Image` widget). Finally, use `drawImage` to draw it to the canvas.

Comment: I did > var decodedImage = await instantiateImageCodec(base64Decode(image));
if (decodedImage!=null) canvas.drawImage(decodedImage,Offset(0,0),brush);
I get error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Codec' is not a subtype of type 'Image'

Comment: Also tried: import 'dart:ui' as UI; var decodedImage = await UI.instantiateImageCodec(base64Decode(image)); 

But the error is the same.

Comment: That's because it *is* a `Codec`. `await codec.getNextFrame()` will get you a `FrameInfo` which has an `image` getter to give you the image.

Comment: Could you please give some code snippet to have a better idea on what I should do, like where do I write this getNextFrame function, I am finding it a little hard to follow. I tried this: decodedImage = await (await UI.instantiateImageCodec(base64Decode(image))).getNextFrame(); but not working